# Crashear / Colgar Programa con intencion c#

Tags: c#, windows

estoy buscando alguna forma de crashear / colgar un programa externo ya ejecutandose en windows , sea Escritura de memoria, memory leak, etc , y si es posible en c#

Esto es para fines de testeo de Windows , lamento no poder dar mas detalles

Comment: Esto no es una pregunta. Estás esperando que hagamos la tarea por ti. Lamentamos no poder ayudar

Comment: Tocará investigar. Quizá [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4284913/13419694) de Stackoverflow te sea útil.

Comment: Podrías decompilar el programa y agregar código que genere el error. Me parece que Telerik tiene un programa para decompilar

Comment: muchas gracias mateo